# Keep track of numbers in a list

Tags: python, list, numpy, sorting

I have a very long list of numbers and I have an if statement that takes out numbers larger than a certain value and puts them in a different list. I want to be able to keep track of the ID in the original list so I an go back and match them to other information. See example below:

```
test_list = [564, 564748, 654, 89, 567, 98]

large_numbers = []

for i in test_list:
    if i >= 600:
        large_numbers.append(i)
```

This works fine and I get:

```
large_numbers = [564748, 654]
```

**However is there any way to assign an ID to each so I know where it was in the original list. Ideally it would output something similar to:**

```
print(ID_of_large_numbers)
```

`[0,1]`

This way I would know it was the 1st and 2nd element of the original list. (My personal list has several 100 elements and I sort it into a numpy array from highest to lowest, so I am unable to find their ID).

Comment: Do you mean the elements index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `enumerate` in your for-loop somehow like that:

```
for idx,i in enumerate(test_list):
    if i >= 600:
        large_numbers.append(i)
        ID_of_large_numbers.append(idx)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with a dict comprehension:

```
test_list = [12, 642]
large_num_by_original_index = {i: n for i, n in enumerate(test_list) if n >= 600}
```

This goes through each element in the list and stores it in the dictionary along with its index. The above dictionary will contain:

```
{1: 642}
```

PS: Choose a better name for the resulting dictionary

Answer (score 0):

```
test_list = [564, 564748, 654, 89, 567, 98]
large_numbers = []
large_numbers_index = []
for i, e in enumerate(test_list):
    if e >= 600:
        large_numbers.append(e)
        large_numbers_index.append(i)
```